# Get word frequency of pandas column containing lists of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'words':[['foo','bar none','scare','bar','foo'],
                              ['race','bar none','scare'],
                              ['ten','scare','crow bird']]})
```

I'm trying to get a word/phrase count of all the list elements in the dataframe colunn. My current solution is:

```
allwords = []

for index, row in test.iterrows():
    for word in row['words']:
        allwords.append(word)
```

```
from collections import Counter
pd.Series(Counter(allwords)).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a faster solution. Note: I'm not using `' '.join()` because I don't want the phrases to be split into individual words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For improve performance dont use `iterrows`:

```
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import chain

a = pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(test['words']))).sort_values(ascending=False)
print (a)
scare        3
foo          2
bar none     2
bar          1
race         1
ten          1
crow bird    1
dtype: int64
```

Pandas only solution:

```
a = pd.Series([y for x in test['words'] for y in x]).value_counts()
print (a)
scare        3
bar none     2
foo          2
bar          1
race         1
crow bird    1
ten          1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's try **[`.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)** with **[`.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)**:

```
pd.value_counts(np.hstack(test['words']))
```

---

```
scare        3
foo          2
bar none     2
ten          1
bar          1
crow bird    1
race         1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Counter`:

```
import collections
words = test['words'].tolist()

collections.Counter([x for sublist in words for x in sublist])
```

---

```
Counter({'foo': 2,
         'bar none': 2,
         'scare': 3,
         'bar': 1,
         'race': 1,
         'ten': 1,
         'crow bird': 1})
```